# Combine -snapshot and -loadvm snap_id in qemu-system

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization

Is it possible somehow to use -snapshot and -loadvm snap_id  together during starting guest by using qemu-system?

Currently, if I use these options together, guest can not be started.

I need to prevent saving data into guest disk to avoid it's growing. -snapshot allows to achive it on the fly, but I also need -loadvm snap_id to to get already booted VM instead of waiting for it's booting.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately QEMU doesn't permit this for the reason that you might save an internal-snapshot (i.e `savevm` command) while running with the flag `-snapshot`. 
This is because of an [edge case](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1184089/comments/3): when you use `-snapshot` QEMU creates a temporary image where all copy-on-writes are saved to. Now if you run `savevm` while in this mode, QEMU will write the internal-snapshot to the temporary image, and once you shut off the machine you lose your snapshot.

To overcome this edge case we have to manually perform what's called an external-snapshot.
Do the following steps to achieve this (https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1184089/comments/2)

1. Run QEMU with `-snapshot` and `-monitor stdio`
2. Hit `Enter` to get the `(qemu)` monitor prompt
3. `migrate "exec: gzip -c > memsnapshot.gz"` or `migrate "exec: cat > memsnapshot"` (for instant load time)
4. Now use `-snapshot` with the above memsnapshot: `qemu-* <whatever flags> -incoming "exec: gzip -c -d snapshot.gz" -snapshot` or `qemu-* <whatever flags> -incoming "exec: cat memsnapshot" -snapshot`

Answer (score 1):

As workaround, I used external snapshot type. So general algorithm is the next:

1. Run guest from basic qcow2 image
2. Do some stuff inside guest
3. Poweroff guest
4. Create external snapshot with the help of qemu-img
5. Run guest from created snapshot
6. Connect to qemu monitor via socket and run savevm command to save current running state of guest
7. Poweroff guest again
8. Start guest anywhere using external snapshot and -loadvm parameter

Regarding mentioned issue a feature request was created four years ago: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1184089